# Reading in a float, somehow it gets changed

Tags: c++

Sorry about the messy code, rushing to finish this for a school project.

I am reading in a series of data from an input file. Cin should be taking in two floats, one latitude, and one longitude. Using the first line from the in file, it should be `4243.636` and `09028.597`. But using Visual Studio debugger, it shows there values to be `4243.63623` and `9028.59668` respectively.

This causes the math I use later to fail. I spent a long time narrowing the math error down to this, but I can't for the life of me figure out why they are getting changed. I tried changing them to doubles, then long doubles. I tried storing it as a string, which worked, but then tried converting it to a float with `stof`, but that gives the same wrong numbers as just storing them as floats to begin with.

I feel like I am doing something really dumb and I just need some help being guided in the right direction. Thanks y'all!

Code:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Input:   $GPRMC sentence for add (A). Distance traveled (D).
//          Average speed (S). Table of records (T).
//
// Output:  Record added. Table of records. Distance traveled.
//          Average speed.
//          
//---------------------------------------------------------------------

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_RECS = 5;
const int EARTH_RADIUIS_MILES = 3959;
const int FEET_IN_MILE = 5280;
const float HALF_CIRCLE = 180;
const float PI = 3.14159f;
const int SECS_IN_HR = 3600;
const int SECS_IN_MIN = 60;
const float FPS_PER_KNOT = 1.68781f;
const int ID1 = 2234;
const int ID2 = 5327;
const int ID3 = 7741;

const int TABLEFIRSTSPACE = 51;
const int TABLESECONDSPACE = 6;
const int TABLE8 = 8;
const int TABLE10 = 10;
const int TABLE11 = 11;
const int TABLE13 = 13;

enum FitBitID_Type 
{ 
   ID_FITBIT1 = ID1, ID_FITBIT2 = ID2, ID_FITBIT3 = ID3
};

enum CommandType 
{
   ADD_CMD = 'A', DISTANCE_TRAVELED_CMD = 'D',
   AVG_SPEED_CMD = 'S', TABLE_PRINT_CMD = 'T'
};

void ReadIn(int &time, float &latNum, float &longNum, float &speedFloat);
void ReadIn();
//void timeBreakdown(int time, int &hours, int &minutes, int &seconds);
//void latLongCalc(float latNum, float longNum, float &latD, float &longD);
//float DegreesToRadians(float degrees);

class FitBit
{
private:
   string strTime[MAX_RECS];
   int totalSecs[MAX_RECS];
   float latitude[MAX_RECS];
   float longitude[MAX_RECS];
   float speed[MAX_RECS];
   int numRecs;//num of records currently stored in the parallel arrays

   void timeBreakdown(int time, int &hours, int &minutes, int &seconds)
   {
      string timeStr = to_string(time);
      hours = stoi(timeStr.substr(0, 2));
      minutes = stoi(timeStr.substr(2, 2));
      seconds = stoi(timeStr.substr(4, 2));
   }

   void latLongCalc(float latNum, float longNum, float &latD, float &longD)
   {
      string latStr = to_string(latNum);
      float degreeLa = stof(latStr.substr(0, 2));
      float minuteLa = stof(latStr.substr(2, 2));
      float secondLa = stof(latStr.substr(5, 3));
      latD = degreeLa + (minuteLa / SECS_IN_MIN) +
         (((secondLa / 1000) * SECS_IN_MIN) / SECS_IN_HR);
      string longStr = to_string(longNum);
      float degreeLo = stof(longStr.substr(0, 2));
      float minuteLo = stof(longStr.substr(2, 2));
      float secondLo = stof(longStr.substr(5, 3));
      longD = degreeLo + (minuteLo / SECS_IN_MIN) +
         (((secondLo / 1000) * SECS_IN_MIN) / SECS_IN_HR); longD = -longD;
   }

   float DegreesToRadians(float degrees)
   {
      return degrees * PI / HALF_CIRCLE;
   }

public:
   FitBit()
   {
      numRecs = 0;
   }
   void addRecord(int time, float latNum, float longNum, 
      float speedFloat)
   {
      int hours, minutes, seconds;
      timeBreakdown(time, hours, minutes, seconds);
      float latD, longD;
      latLongCalc(latNum, longNum, latD, longD);
      hours *= SECS_IN_MIN; minutes += hours; minutes *= SECS_IN_MIN;
      seconds += minutes; speedFloat *= FPS_PER_KNOT;
      string timeStr = to_string(time);
      if (numRecs < MAX_RECS)
      {
         strTime[numRecs] = timeStr; totalSecs[numRecs] = seconds;
         latitude[numRecs] = latD; longitude[numRecs] = longD;
         speed[numRecs] = speedFloat;
         numRecs++;
      }
      else
      {
         for (int i = 1; i < numRecs; i++)
         {
            strTime[i - 1] = strTime[i]; totalSecs[i - 1] = totalSecs[i];
            latitude[i - 1] = latitude[i];
            longitude[i - 1] = longitude[i]; speed[i - 1] = speed[i];
         }
         strTime[numRecs] = timeStr; totalSecs[numRecs] = seconds;
         latitude[numRecs] = latD; longitude[numRecs] = longD;
         speed[numRecs] = speedFloat;
      }
   }
   float distanceBetweenEarthCoordinates(float lat1, float lon1, 
                                       float lat2, float lon2)
   {
      float dLat, dLon, a, c;
      lat1 = DegreesToRadians(lat1);
      lon1 = DegreesToRadians(lon1);
      lat2 = DegreesToRadians(lat2);
      lon2 = DegreesToRadians(lon2);
      dLat = (lat2 - lat1);
      dLon = (lon2 - lon1);

      a = sin(dLat / 2) * sin(dLat / 2) +
         sin(dLon / 2) * sin(dLon / 2) * cos(lat1) * cos(lat2);
      c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a));

      return ((EARTH_RADIUIS_MILES * c) * FEET_IN_MILE);
   }
   float Distance()
   {
      if (!(numRecs <= 1))
      {
         float total = 0;
         for (int i = 1; i < numRecs; i++)
         {
            float x = distanceBetweenEarthCoordinates(latitude[i-1],
               longitude[i-1], latitude[i], longitude[i]);
            total += x;
         }
         return total;
      }
      return 0;
   }
   float DistanceForTable(int i)
   {
      if (!(i < 1))
      {
         return distanceBetweenEarthCoordinates(latitude[i - 1],
            longitude[i - 1], latitude[i], longitude[i]);
      }
      return 0;
   }
   void PrintTable()
   {
      cout << left << setw(TABLE8) << "Time" << setw(TABLE10)
         << "Latitude" << setw(TABLE10) << "Longitude" << setw(TABLE11)
         << "Speed" << setw(TABLE13) << "Distance" << setw(TABLE10)
         << "Average" << setw(TABLE13) << "Acceleration" << endl << right
         << setw(TABLEFIRSTSPACE) << "Traveled(ft)" 
         << setw(TABLESECONDSPACE) << "Speed" << endl;
      if (numRecs > 0)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < numRecs; i++)
         {
            cout << left << setw(TABLE8) << strTime[i];
            cout << left << setw(TABLE10) << latitude[i];
            cout << left << setw(TABLE10) << longitude[i];
            cout << left << setw(TABLE11) << speed[i];
            cout << left << setw(TABLE13) << DistanceForTable(i);
            cout << left << setw(TABLE10) << 200.0;
            cout << left << setw(TABLE13) << 1.0101 << endl;
         }
      }
   }
};

void ProcessCommandForFitBit(FitBit & bit, CommandType command,
   FitBitID_Type FitBitID);

int main()
{
   cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(15);
   char cmd; int id;

   FitBit bit1, bit2, bit3;

   while (cin)
   {
      cin >> cmd >> id;
      FitBitID_Type FitBitID = FitBitID_Type(id);
      CommandType command = CommandType(cmd); 
      if (FitBitID == ID_FITBIT1)
         ProcessCommandForFitBit(bit1, command, FitBitID);
      else if (FitBitID == ID_FITBIT2)
         ProcessCommandForFitBit(bit2, command, FitBitID);
      else if (FitBitID == ID_FITBIT3)
         ProcessCommandForFitBit(bit3, command, FitBitID);
   }

   cout << "Normal Termination of Program 5.";
   return 0;
}

void ProcessCommandForFitBit(FitBit & bit, CommandType command,
                             FitBitID_Type FitBitID)
{
   int returnedDistance = 0, returnedAvgSpeed = 0;
   int time = 0; float latNum = 0, longNum = 0, speedFloat = 0;

   switch (command)
   {
   case ADD_CMD:
      //ReadIn(time, latNum, longNum, speedFloat);
      ReadIn();
      //bit.addRecord(time, latNum, longNum, speedFloat);
      cout << "Record added for FitBit with ID " << FitBitID << endl;
      break;
   case DISTANCE_TRAVELED_CMD:
      //returnedDistance = bit.Distance();
      cout << "Distance Traveled in feet for FitBit with ID "
           << FitBitID << " is " << returnedDistance << endl;
      break;
   case AVG_SPEED_CMD:

      cout << "Average Speed for FitBit with ID " << FitBitID
           << " is " << returnedAvgSpeed << endl;
      break;
   case TABLE_PRINT_CMD:
      cout << "Records for FitBit with ID " << FitBitID << endl;
      bit.PrintTable();
      break;
   }
}

void ReadIn()
{
   //int &time, float &latNum, float &longNum, float &speedFloat
   int time = 0; float latNum, longNum, speedFloat;
   string trash;
   cin >> trash >> time >> trash >> latNum >> trash >> longNum
      >> trash >> speedFloat >> trash >> trash >> trash >> trash;
   cout << time << " " << latNum << " " << longNum << " " << speedFloat << endl;
}
```

Input File:

```
A 2234 $GPRMC 204849 A 4243.636 N 09028.597 W 000.0 065.5 091297 000.2 W*7F
A 2234 $GPRMC 204851 A 4243.636 N 09028.594 W 006.4 074.4 091297 000.2 W*76
A 2234 $GPRMC 204853 A 4243.638 N 09028.586 W 011.7 067.9 091297 000.2 W*73
A 2234 $GPRMC 204855 A 4243.641 N 09028.574 W 014.2 067.5 091297 000.2 W*7A
T 2234
D 2234
S 2234
A 2234 $GPRMC 204903 A 4243.662 N 09028.593 W 018.7 066.2 090108 000.2 W*7A
T 2234
D 2234
S 2234
T 5327
D 5327
S 5327
A 5327 $GPRMC 204905 A 4273.667 N 09047.499 W 021.6 064.5 090108 000.2 W*78
T 5327
D 5327
S 5327
A 5327 $GPRMC 204907 A 4273.671 N 09047.480 W 027.3 065.4 090108 000.2 W*73
T 5327
D 5327
S 5327
A 7741 $GPRMC 204909 A 4273.679 N 09047.459 W 026.5 066.8 090108 000.2 W*77
A 7741 $GPRMC 204913 A 4273.689 N 09047.418 W 031.7 068.6 090108 000.2 W*7F
T 7741
D 7741
S 7741
```

Comment: That's because of the precision limits of a `float`.  When you tried `double`, did you change _every_ `float` to `double`, and `stof` to `stod`?

Comment: I did change everything to a double to see if that would help, I did NOT try the stof to stod, I will try that right when I get out class today. Thanks!

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) explains the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer is in the number. If i understand correctly the first zero in you number `09028.597` is significant.

If this is True you will never reach your goal with float.

But you can with String. In fact if you take the full input string then you can start elaborate it from the "."(dot) to the left and then to the right (managing this kind of special case) filling the integer(or float) number in the way you prefer. In this way you don't lose the information about zero.

Comment: This is exactly it. I was totally going about the problem wrong. It's split up into three sections: degrees, minutes and seconds. I should have set it to a string and done the same thing I did to break up the time. Thanks for the help! You saved me lol

Comment: Perfect! I'm happy to help you. Please vote up if you think is correct

Comment: I did upvote, but I don't have enough rep for it to be public lol